# Website live chat app with WhatsApp integration

Tags: web-apps, chat, whatsapp

Is there a live customer chat app that has WhatsApp integration?

For example, I will go to that sales website and ask something in live support with my mobile number. Then they will answer me via WhatsApp, we continue on chat there. Are there any applications?

Does not have to be gratis. Can be a hosted service or a self-hosted application (my company will want to see all to compare).

Comment: Free or Paid? Online service or self-hosted app?

Comment: All please. My company will want to see all to compare.

Comment: wouldn't be easier to put a live chat with an automatic answer sending the visitor your whatsapp number? everytime someone interacts with your website they can choose to continue through whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try out [userlike.com](http://userlike.com) - breaking through communication barriers through unified messaging. You, as an operator, respond from the dashboard directly to where your visitors messaged you from, including WhatsApp!

Comment: Marta, are your affiliated with userlike.com at all?  If so, that's fine, but please edit your answer to reflect that piece of information.

Comment: I hadn't heard of userlike.com before, and it looks interesting. However, I cannot see whether they have an iOS app (for agents) that receives notifications whenever there is a new chat (and lets them respond to customers).

Comment: @Marta I wonder what your thoughts are about my question here about a chat widget: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49458/14834